# Moving average by id/group with a defined interval in python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, numpy, moving-average

Given is a csv dataset with the following columns and values (example).
I want to **add a new column** in my csv data with a **moving average** of S1 according to each id. S1 are my measurements. The timeframe t should be 3.That's how my dataset currently looks.

```
id  S1  
1   3
1   4
1   2
1   6
1   9
2   3
2   1
2   2
2   3
2   8
2   6
3   1
3   4
3   2
3   8
3   5
```

And that's what I wanna do:

```
id  S1   movA  
1   3    NaN
1   4    NaN
1   2    3.000
1   6    4.000
1   9    5.667
2   3    NaN
2   1    NaN
2   2    2.000
2   3    2.000
2   8    4.333
2   6    5.333
3   1    NaN
3   4    NaN
3   2    2.333
3   8    4.667
3   5    5.000
```

Comment: Can you provide code from an attempt that you have tried?

Comment: also what do you mean by variable here? changing along S1? If so on what criteria?

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe the wrong word. What i meant is, that it doesn't matter if the timeframe or time window is 3 or 5 or whatever. I just want to have an additional column with a moving average of the values from S1. For each ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `groupby` and `rolling` with `mean`

```
g = df.groupby('id').S1
rolls = [2, 3, 4, 5]
pd.concat([g.rolling(i).mean() for i in rolls], axis=1, keys=rolls)
```

[image]

Comment: That's a good approach. thanks. But im not sure how to add this as an additional column to my dataset.

# idx1 = df.groupby('id')['RUL'].nsmallest(30).reset_index(drop=True, level=0).index
# df['label1'] = np.where(df.index.isin(idx1), 1, 0)

Comment: That's a good approach. Thanks. But I'm not sure how to add this as an additional column to my dataset.

I mean that's another case, but I want to add this coloumn like that:

idx1 = df.groupby('id')['RUL'].nsmallest(30).reset_index(drop=True, level=0).index

df['label1'] = np.where(df.index.isin(idx1), 1, 0)

Comment: The most effective part of any question is to provide a sample of what data you are working with ***and*** a sample of what you expect as output.  I'm confused as to what you actually want or need.  I provided this answer because I thought it might be helpful.  If you can go back and better articulate what your are trying to achieve, I can help you more effectively.  That means, take the time to piece together what the result should look like from the sample you already provided in the question.

Comment: Excuse me for my inaccuracy. I've edited my question.Thanks for your help.

Comment: The question is still open. Your answer is absolutely right. But how can I add a column with this function to 'id' and 'S1' as shown above?

Comment: Alright. Got it. I just have to add `value` in the end.